# ValueError: object too deep for desired array while using cross correlation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation, cross-correlation

I am trying to investigate the cross correlation of two DataFrames. The code is given here:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[7191, 7275, 9889, 9934, 9633, 9924, 9650, 9341, 8820, 8784, 8869]})

np.correlate(df1, df2)
```

But I get this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XedfI.jpg

Any ideas?

Comment: `df1.join(df2).corr()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error as you're passing as a dataframe, which is 2D. `np.correlate` is for cross-correlation of two 1-dimensional sequences. So try.

```
np.correlate(df1.squeeze(), df2.squeeze())
```

which outputs `array([80556], dtype=int64)`.

---

## Edit

Based on your suggestion, try

```
# You will need to change your column names, like 
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"B":[7191, 7275, 9889, 9934, 9633, 9924, 9650, 9341, 8820, 8784, 8869]})

df1.join(df2).corr()
```

which outputs

```
            A           B
A   1.000000    -0.174287
B   -0.174287   1.000000
```

As suggested by piRSquared in the comments, you can also use `df1.corrwith(df2)` to return a single value.

Comment: Hey,
Thank you so much for your help. But in fact I was looking for a value between -1 and +1 like it is in normal correlation. How do you think I should apply this code to find it?

Comment: Other alternatives `df1.corrwith(df2)` or `df1.A.corr(df2.A)`

Comment: @diabolik feel free to up-vote the answer in addition to selecting as the chosen answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `scipy.stats` function  `pearsonr`. So after the imports:

```
pearson = pearsonr(df1['A'].values,df2['A'].values)
```